# Acquisition of string c

Tags: c, getchar

This is the code of a simple code of game of anagram:

```
#define NP 5
#define LP 10
void anagrammi() {
    srand(time (NULL));
    char words[NP][LP] = {"cane", "gatto", "gallo", "rana", "ibis"};
    typedef struct { 
    char parola[LP];
    int usati[LP];
    char anagramma[LP];
    }an ;
int a, len, i, j, cont;
char merda[LP], c;
an yoda;

a = rand()%5;
strcpy(yoda.parola, words[a]);
len = strlen(yoda.parola);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
yoda.usati[i] = len+2;
}
i = 0;
while (i < len){
    cont = 0;
    a = rand()%len;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
if (a == yoda.usati[j]) cont++; 
} if (cont == 0) { 
yoda.usati[i] = a;
yoda.anagramma[i] = yoda.parola[a];
i++;
}
}
j = 0;
cont = 0;
yoda.anagramma[i] = '\0';
printf("Anagramma di %s ? ", yoda.anagramma);
c = getchar() ;
while( c != '\n' && j < LP ){
merda[j] = c ;
j++ ;
c = getchar(); }
merda[j] = '\0';
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (merda[i] =! yoda.parola[i]) cont++;
    printf("\n%d", cont);
    printf("\n%c", merda[i]);
    printf("\n%c", yoda.parola[i]);
} 
if (cont =! 0) printf("\nFALSE");
else printf ("\nTRUE");
}
```

The program goes, but when I insert the word and compare this to the original word, the final output is always FALSE, even if I put the right word. The problem occurs also without \0.Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks to the answer, this is the perfectly working programm:

```
void anagrammi() {
    srand(time (NULL));
    char words[NP][LP] = {"cane", "gatto", "gallo", "rana", "ibis"};
    typedef struct { 
    char parola[LP];
    int usati[LP];
    char anagramma[LP];
    }an ;
int a, len, i, j, cont;
char merda[LP], c;
an yoda;

a = rand()%5;
strcpy(yoda.parola, words[a]);
len = strlen(yoda.parola);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
yoda.usati[i] = len+2;
}
i = 0;
while (i < len){
    cont = 0;
    a = rand()%len;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
if (a == yoda.usati[j]) cont++; 
} if (cont == 0) { 
yoda.usati[i] = a;
yoda.anagramma[i] = yoda.parola[a];
i++;
}
}
j = 0;
cont = 0;
yoda.anagramma[i] = '\0';
printf("Anagramma di %s ? ", yoda.anagramma);
c = getchar() ;
while( c != '\n' && j < LP ){
merda[j] = c ;
j++ ;
c = getchar(); }
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (merda[i] != yoda.parola[i]) cont++;

} 
i = strlen(merda);
if (cont != 0 || i > len ) printf("\nNON HAI INDOVINATO");
else printf ("\nHAI INDOVINATO");

}
```

Comment: `(cont =! 0)` that should be `(cont != 0)`

Comment: Tanks, it's not possible, always these piffle.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings...

Comment: And never except code that compiles with warnings (except in very, very rare circumstances where the warning is expected and understood -- something you will not encounter anytime in the near future).

Comment: completely unrelated to programming, what's that language, and what "yoda" means in it? :)

Answer (score 1):

`(cont =! 0)` that should be `(cont != 0)`
                    – kaylum